# Page Not found after reload page AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have setup project in Angular js. I set base tag with href="/demo/" But when I try to reload my page I am getting error of 404 page not found. My .htaccess is

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set `href='domain root'` as default in base tag.
Base tag is originally specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page.

There can only be one single `<base>` element in a document, and it must be inside the `<head>` element.

Also it's not relative with .htaccess file.

By the way, In angular.js route development mode, it's added `#`.  Looks like `'/annonser/1/'` to `'/#!/item/1'`

If you try to delete `#` using .htaccess is bad in practice.

Comment: I already set <base href="/demo/"> in <head> section. But still it is not working.

Comment: How about set <base href=''/> not /demo/